Code packaged in NuGet package is not visible
I've packaged and published my code generator, including code fixes and a DLL specifically for the attribute that triggers everything. The attribute isn't available when I add the package to my .NET 8 project.
If I look at the package with NuGet Package Explorer I see this:

The attribute defined in the DLL is public. What am I missing to make it usable?
This is what I have in the project that does the packing:
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage);_AddAnalyzersToOutput</TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\RegisterWithDi.Attribute\RegisterWithDi.Attribute.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\RegisterWithDi.CodeFixes\RegisterWithDi.CodeFixes.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\RegisterWithDi\RegisterWithDi.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\README.md">
        <Pack>True</Pack>
        <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="_AddAnalyzersToOutput">
    <ItemGroup>
        <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="$(OutputPath)\RegisterWithDi.dll" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" />
        <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="$(OutputPath)\RegisterWithDi.CodeFixes.dll" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" />
        <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="$(OutputPath)\RegisterWithDi.Attribute.dll" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" />
        <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="$(OutputPath)\RegisterWithDi.Attribute.dll" PackagePath="lib\netstandard2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>


Do you have a full [mre] you can share? How do you add the nuget to the project?
